# Visual Studio 2019 continues to look for the previous DbContext even after replacing it with a new one

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

> Disclaimer: I am posting a self-answer to this. Even though it's something that's rather unusual to do, hopefully someone will benefit from reading this.

I recently replaced my original Entity Framework Core `DbContext` with a new one because I renamed the database (among other things). Let's call the original one `OriginalDbContext` and `NewDbContext` for convenience.

The table structure itself remained unchanged.

Naturally, I had to replace all instances of `OriginalDbContext` with `NewDbContext`. I was expecting that, once I did that, it would simply compile (since I didn't make any database changes other than replace `OriginalDbContext` with `NewDbContext`). However, even after I did that, I got numerous error messages stating to the effect that `OldDbContext` did not have a definition for my table clases.

I searched all files in my solution for any reference to `OriginalDbContext` and found none. I even deleted `OriginalDbContext.cs` entirely (including in version control).

Why would it continue to "look for" `OriginalDbContext` even though I verified that it was removed from all of my `.cs` files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally did a "Find All" on the entire directory. It turns out that the only place that referred to `OriginalDbContext` was one of my publish profiles (which did not appear when I searched only in the solution). I deleted the profile and was able to compile again.

I guess the broader lesson here is that there could be references to your `DbContext` class that do not appear in your code base and may not even show up if you do a "Find All" on the entire solution.

Worse yet, when I double-clicked the original error messages, it made it appear like the errors were coming from my code base.